# Background image in Menustrip Item disappeared on hover & click

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, menustrip

I'm creating a windows application. In that application I need to show images on `MenuStrip` control items instead of text. Background image is working fine but the image got disappeared on hover and click.

## Image on menu item

[image]

## Disappeared on click/hover

[image]

Can some one have any idea, what to do to show a different image or same image on hover or click.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `BackgroundImage` property in the designer, which disappears on mouse hover.

Should set the `Image` property instead.

To show a different image on hover, register handlers for both `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events, and change the Image property from the handlers.

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.toolStripMenuItem1.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.Hover;
}

private void toolStripMenuItem1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.toolStripMenuItem1.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.Normal;
}
```

**Edit:** For your requirement to show a different `BackgroundImage` when hover, use a custom render (first remove the `MouseEnter/MouseLeave` code above, and set both `Image/BackgroundImage` to *none* in designer).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    menuStrip1.Renderer = new BackgroundImageRenderer(); //menuStrip1 is the container for the toolstrip menu items.
}

private class BackgroundImageRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {                
        if (e.Item.Name == "toolStripMenuItem1")
        {                    
            Image backgroundImage = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.Normal;
            if (e.Item.Selected)
                backgroundImage = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.Hover;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, e.Item.Width, e.Item.Height);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My requirement is to set the image as background, tried to change it through the way suggested by you but not working.